# How to create Layout on android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to create the Layout like this.
[image]

I only need to know that how to implement the hand symbol
when load the application in first time.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preferences for that.
Set the value for a key `{firsTime,true}`.

When you get the value as true, show the hand symbol.

After that 
make the value as false so that it won't be showed again.

Comment: sorry ,I need the layout dialog,

Comment: Use this style only for background( this should not be applicable for hand symbol).<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>

Answer (score 0):

you can one transparent/semi-transparent view above the activity Layout and show whatever you want or here are some good libraries
https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView and https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1408.